# why does there is no update in Node *root?

Tags: c, struct, binary-search-tree, pass-by-reference

This is a very simple example for inserting a number.

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *left, *right;

} node;

node * newNode(int val) {
    node* n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->data=val;
    n->left=NULL;
    n->right=NULL;
    return n; }

void insert(node* node, int key) {    
    if (node == NULL)
        node = newNode(key);
}

int main() {
    node *root = NULL;
    insert(root, 5);

    printf("%d\n", root->data);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, Why does the `printf` print nothing when I insert 5 in `root`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C all arguments are passed *by value*. That means the value is *copied* into the argument variable, and when you do the assignment `node = newNode(key);` you only assign to the local `node` variable.

There are two solutions to this problem:

1. *Return* the new node instead:

   ```
   node* insert(node* the_node, int key) {    
       if (the_node == NULL)
           the_node = newNode(key);
       return the_node;
   }

   ...

   root = insert(root, 5);
   ```
2. Emulate *pass by reference*, which can be done by passing a pointer to the variable using the address-of operator `&`:

   ```
   void insert(node** the_node, int key) {    
       if (*the_node == NULL)
           *the_node = newNode(key);
   }

   ...

   insert(&root, 5);
   ```

Comment: I know that all arguments are passed by value but I'm confused because I passed a pointer so why does the compiler create a copy of `root` pointer?

Comment: @ModyElSayed The value of a pointer is where it's pointing. It's this value that is copied in your code. If you want to modify the actual `root` variable, then you need to pass a pointer *to the variable*.

Answer (score 0):

You passed the pointer `root` to the function `insert` by value. You can imagine the function definition and its call the following way

```
node *root = NULL;
insert(root, 5);

//...

void insert( /* node* node, int key */ ) {    
    node* node = root;
    int key = 5;
    if (node == NULL)
        node = newNode(key);
}
```

As you see the function deals with a copy of the pointer root. Changing the copy that is the value in the local variable `node` does not influence on the value stored in the pointer `root`.

You have to pass the pointer root by reference. For example

```
void insert(node** node, int key) {    
    if (*node == NULL)
        *node = newNode(key);
}

int main() {
    node *root = NULL;
    insert(&root, 5);
    //...
```

In the terms of C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. In this case the object will be accessible in the function through the passed pointer.

Pay attention to that it would be more safe to define the function `newNode` the following way

```
node * newNode( int val ) 
{
    node *n = malloc( sizeof( node ) );

    if ( n != NULL )
    {
        n->data  = val;
        n->left  = NULL;
        n->right = NULL;
    }

    return n; 
}
```

In this case the function `insert` can look like

```
int insert( node **node, int key ) 
{
    while ( *node != NULL )
    {
        if ( key < ( *node )->data )
        {
            node = &( *node )->left;
        }
        else
        {
            node = &( *node )->right;
        }
    }

    *node = newNode( key );

    return *node != NULL;
}
```